# ошибка при компиляции в qt creator

Tags: qt

Скачал с официального сайта offline сборку Qt 5.7.1 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2015, 923 MB).

Запускаю первый проект Qt Widgets Application (в пути нет лишних пробелов и кириллицы).

В коде ничего не меняю, остается стандартным, запускаю Run и вылетает такая ошибка

```
Error while building/deploying project untitled1 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.1 MSVC2015_64bit)
When executing step "qmake"
```

Гугл выдал такой ответ: либо кириллица либо лишние пробелы в пути. Перепроверил несколько раз, с этим проблем быть не должно.

В чем ошибка? При установке qt никаких проблем не вылетало..

**UPDATE:**

В настройках проекта build directory подсвечивается красным и при наведении на него мышкой всплывает ошибка: the path "..." does not exist.

На что должен указывать build directory?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: то, что оно выделено красным - это нормально. Просто этот путь ещё не создан. Как только хоть чуточку скомпилируется

А компилироваться может по той причине, что не установлен компилятор от 2015 студии.

Comment: хоть сборка и называется Qt 5.7.1 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2015, 923 MB), но на самом деле никакого вижуал студио компилятора там нет, его вам надо устанавливать отдельно

Answer (score 4):

Скачивай нормальный компилятор. Заново на qt.io и качай MinGW версию на 32 бита... Это не зависит от разрядности твоей системы, просто иначе тебе придётся скачивать visual studio и настраивать компилятор